# Terminal nano won't quit

Tags: terminal, nano

Hi I am trying to quit nano, I don't need to save any changes. I have tried ctrl x and press n for not saving changes  but it won't quit. It just switches between saying new file and [ Switched to JAVA_HOME= ] see screen shot

[image]

Comment: Can any one help with this? I need to use terminal for uni and I'm starting to panic

Answer (score 0):

Its OK I fixed it by deleting the bash history